# Exploding loss in encoder/decoder model PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to build a text to speech model in PyTorch using an encoder/decoder architecture on librispeech 100hr dataset. The model essentially takes in text and outputs a mel spectrogram but I'm facing an issue where my loss explodes on the 2nd to 3rd batch irrespective of batch size.

I'm probably doing something stupid in my trainer but I'm not sure what! Does anyone have any insight?

Minimal train.py - [gist](https://gist.github.com/michaelliangaustralia/1e231659e01ee858ad964e85abe0a060)

model.py - [gist](https://gist.github.com/michaelliangaustralia/ef5e3aed0aeebe7c2688ff301514ac9a)

This is the terminal output when trying to run the training file

```
loss tensor(0.2049, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<MSELossBackward0>)
loss tensor(8.0709e+17, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<MSELossBackward0>)
loss tensor(9.1250e+29, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<MSELossBackward0>)
... [loss will be inf]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calculating your loss only on the last mini batch, you should accumulate your loss and do backward on the accumulated loss

```
loss = 0
for b in range(BSIZE):
    
    batch_ms_pred_list = []
    for i in tqdm(range(audio[b].shape[0])):
        ms_pred, dec_hidden, dec_cell = decoder_model(dec_input, dec_hidden, dec_cell, enc_outputs[b].unsqueeze(0))

        if random.uniform(0, 1) < p_teacher_forcing: # teacher forcing
            dec_input = audio[b][i].unsqueeze(0).to(device)
        else: # no teacher forcing
            dec_input = ms_pred

        # append mspred
        batch_ms_pred_list.append(ms_pred)

    # accumulate loss
    batch_ms_pred_list = torch.stack(batch_ms_pred_list).squeeze()
    loss += loss_fn(batch_ms_pred_list, audio[b].to(device))
    print('loss', loss)
    
loss.backward()

optimizer.step()
```